# Current state of ETH Oracles?

Tags: solidity, oracles

Current state of ETH Oracles ? Code examples would be great.

**My question is what would you use today for a random number function ? Or for a cron job like functionality ? Would you use it in production ? What are the best oracles, working and active projects, to watch out for ?**

---

**https://github.com/provable-things looks good.**

I see **ChainLink** is by far the most adopted. Articles are also suggesting the following problems :

- ChainLink inputs cannot be verified without trust.
- ChainLink has a large attack surface.
- ChainLink’s reward and punishment model are decoupled

[image]

**Alternatives** have barely any article or working code example on github/stackexchange :

- Near Protocol
- NEST Protocol
- Supra Oracles
- Flux Oracle
- Band Protocol
- ... many other

And projects like **ethereum-alarm-clock** have been long gone.